# Multi Project / Users / System Global Git Ignore Solution

Tags: git

I have multiple git repos stored on a central server (--bare --shared).
These repos are checked out by multiple users across multiple servers (or their own local workstations).

Now I have a problem.  They all have slightly different .gitignore files at their root directory.  As I started to rectify this, it dawned on me that this has to be a common  problem and should have an elegant solution.  (Also, I don't want to do this more than once, a good programmer is lazy right?)

How can I best achieve the following;

1) Upon new repo creation on the server automatically have the latest .gitignore
2) Have a SINGLE centralized gitignore file for all repos that when updated, gets propgated to all other repos.  (Ideally on the server).

This way, if I need to add something, I don;t have to copy paste to 20 different repos.

Comment: we do it the other way around, every user has a global gitignore file (in his home dir) and this global gitignore file is managed along with other dotfiles in a central repo. project specific gitignore entries are of course possible as well, but very little needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard way to achieve that for a central repo.  You might want to write a script that would fetch from a central location and commit any changes to all the repos that you have on the central server.